# QSortPolicy::Material option usage in Qt3D

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

In Qt3d, the **FrameGraph** must be given a **QSortPolicy** to determine the draw order.

The options are `StateChangeCost`, `FrontToBack`, `BackToFront` and `Material`. How does the `Material` option work?

The doc for [QSortPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3drender-qsortpolicy.html) just says:

> Qt3DRender::QSortPolicy::Material:
>      sort the objects based on their material value

What is the material value, can we modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Qt3DRender::QSortPolicy::Material` will use a hash of the material shader to sort the objects.

This means that it guarantees that the same order is kept as long as the shader remains the same. However this also means that there is no user-friendly way to know what the order will be before trying.